# Writing to database from CKEDITOR

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm trying to write to a database using CKEditor.. when I press submit it dies and says localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

I only want to save the textarea into a row in database so I can then read the row on to another page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <title>Classic editor replacing a textarea</title>
    <script src="http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.0/standard-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="editor1" action="save.php" method="post" >

    <textarea cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10">
    </textarea>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </p>
    </form>

    <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

PHP script

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   // Putting data from form into variables to be manipulated
   $text = $_POST['editor1'];

   $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die ("Can't connect");
   mysql_select_db("managerMessage",$conn);

   // Getting the form variables and then placing their values into the MySQL table
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO text (textarea) VALUES ("mysql_real_escape_string($text)");
}
?>
```

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*`API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` with prepared statements

Comment: did you get the ckeditor value in $text variable?

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: @Jens In PHP the concatenation character is `.` (dot) not `+` (plus)

Comment: You miss`.` to concatinate your string: mysql_query("INSERT INTO text (textarea) VALUES (".mysql_real_escape_string($text).")";

Comment: @jens is correct and also missing submit button name in form so you have to add   <input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Submit">

Answer (score 0):

You are not concatenating the value correctly in this statement and also text data in a query like this should be wrapped in quotes

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO text (textarea) VALUES ("mysql_real_escape_string($text)");
```

This is a corrected verion of your code

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO text 
                    (textarea) 
             VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($text) . "')");
```

A simpler piece of code would be to read and probably maintain would be

```
$t = mysql_real_escape_string($text);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO text (textarea) VALUES ('$t')");
```

> I would be remiss if I did not remind you that
>
> Every time you use [the `mysql_`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
>    database extension in new code
>    **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
>   If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions.
>   [Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

**EDIT RE: not saving the data to the database**

Add some error checking to your code like so:

```
$t = mysql_real_escape_string($text);
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO text (textarea) VALUES ('$t')");
if ( ! $result ) {
    echo mysql_error();
    exit;
}
```

Once you know the error, if one exists, you can start work on fixing it.